# GPU KDF hasher (instead of cracker)

Tags: cuda, gpu, cracking, pbkdf2

So I've been keeping up with GPU crackers and they are quite impressive. I've seen some articles saying someone got up to 384 billion passwords a second. We've been using PBKDF2 with random salt instead of just one time hashes but it can definitely eat up your CPU. I was wondering instead of a cracker, is it possible to use something like NVIDIA Cuda to run PBKDF2 or something similar in a faster more distributed way? Has anyone tried to do this yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the area, but a Google search reveals that PBKDF2 has been successfully implemented on the GPU:

http://daimi.au.dk/~jot2re/cuda/index.html

Note that AMD GPUs may be better than Nvidia for this use case, if SHA-256 hashing performance has any correspondence with PBKDF2:

https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/496471/cuda-programming-and-performance/amd-radeon-3x-faster-on-bitcoin-mining-sha-256-hashing-performance/1